# Any way at all of improving iOS current location?

Tags: ios, gps, location

I am on a search for ultra accurate gps for iOS development. CoreLocations best is still 10 metres off most times, and jumps about. Within the commercial bounds of iOS development, is this defiantly the very best accuracy we have? Any work arounds? Interested to know how close to perfection i can get it.

I know this is not a normal code question, but it's relevant and will help many others too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming question

Comment: This is not software issue and there is nothing you can do. [How accurate is the location detection on the iPhone's Find My iPhone app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238484/how-accurate-is-the-location-detection-on-the-iphones-find-my-iphone-app)

Comment: It really is. It doesn't show code that's all.

Comment: It is about hardware limitations and it shows lack of research. There is plenty of info around about location accuracy not just on iOS but on other devices and platforms, too.

Comment: The 10m accuracy is a limitation of the GPS system, not of iOS specifically. If you search for DGPS information you will see that there are solutions for iOS but it requires additional, external hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately 10 meters is an ideal accuracy for iPhone. In real it may be even worse. If you are developing some kind of fitness application take a look at [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). It allows to get pretty accurate track on iPhone data.

Comment: Exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. Thank you.